# adding an image to Imageview from Document folder Not loading

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, ipad

I am trying to figure to rather simple problem for a while now with no success. I am saving a file to my Documents directory on the Device and trying to load it using an Image View later on. I verified that the file is actually there. Why is my Image not showing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code where I am trying to load the image into the ImageView:

```
 -(void)loadFileFromDocumentFolder:(NSString *) filename
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString: filename] ];

    NSLog(@"outputPath: %@", outputPath);
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage new];
    [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:outputPath];

    if (theImage)
    {
        display = [UIImageView new];
        display = [display initWithImage:theImage];

        [self.view addSubview:display];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are somethings wrong with you code.

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage new];
```

In this line you create a new `UIImage` object but you do nothing with it.

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:outputPath]
```

This class method will return a `UIImage` object with the image load from the file.

You do the same thing with the `UIImageView`.

```
NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithString: filename] ];
```

Also there is not need to `[NSString stringWithString: filename]` you just create an extra string which is not need since `filename` is already a string.

Your code should work like this:

```
 -(void)loadFileFromDocumentFolder:(NSString *) filename {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *outputPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename ];

    NSLog(@"outputPath: %@", outputPath);
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:outputPath];

    if (theImage) {
        display = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
        [self.view addSubview:display];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

chang code with:

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:outputPath];

if (theImage)
{
    display = [UIImageView alloc]  initWithImage:theImage];
}
```